# Get next occurrence of day and hour in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am attempting to implement a countdown timer to a specific point in time in the future. This point in time is always the same day of the week and hour, and is based on UTC time.

I am attempting to write a general function that given a day of the week and an hour, it will return a date object that represents that criteria in the future.

Examples:

`getNextOccuranceOfUTCDayAndHour(1, 7);`

Get the next occurrence of 7 am on Monday. If today is Monday, 5/25/2015 @ midnight UTC, then this function should return a Date object representing Monday 6/1/2015 7 am UTC.

`getNextOccuranceOfUTCDayAndHour(3, 13);`

Get the next occurrence of 1 pm on Wednesday. If today is Tuesday, 5/26/2015 @ midnight UTC, then this function should return a Date object representing Wednesday 5/27/2015 1 pm UTC.

I have attempted to write a function to do this and I have included the snippet below, but it only seems to work for some dates and not others. It's incredibly unreliable. I would prefer not to use Moment.js.

```js
function getNextOccuranceOfUTCDayAndHour(day, hour) {
  d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getUTCDate() + (7 + day - d.getUTCDay()) % 7)
  d.setUTCHours(hour, 0, 0, 0);
  return d;
}

function format_seconds(t) {
  var d = Math.floor(t / 86400);
  var h = Math.floor(t % 86400 / 3600);
  var m = Math.floor(t % 3600 / 60);
  var s = Math.floor(t % 3600 % 60);
  return ((d > 0 ? d + " d. " : "") +
    (h > 0 ? h + " h. " : "") +
    (m > 0 ? m + " m. " : "") +
    s + " s.");
}

function update() {
  var next_occurance = getNextOccuranceOfUTCDayAndHour(1, 7);
  $('#next_occurance').text(next_occurance);
  var ms = next_occurance - new Date();
  $('#countdown').text(format_seconds(Math.floor(ms / 1000)));
}

$(function() {
  update();
  setInterval(update, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="next_occurance">Next Occurance</p>
<p id="countdown">Countdown</p>
```

**Edit:** Some examples of expected vs. returned values. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2j49q0ak/)

Comment: Could you include a few examples of dates that do work and those that don’t?

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/2j49q0ak/

Comment: The second example returns Monday for me (my timezone is UTC+02:00)… even with `.toUTCString()` at the end of `return d`.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work in my time zone, then, considering I'm using UTC functions and UTC time exclusively. My time zone is UTC-7.

Comment: Well, one of your method calls is still `d.setDate` instead of `d.setUTCDate`, though it doesn’t solve the issue…

Comment: Oh, wow, that actually fixes the second example for me. The only problem now is the scenario where it returns today if today is Monday, even if the time now is after the time specified in the function. The result should be 7 days after.

Comment: I'm sorry, that actually fixes both problems, as the first example is correct. Can you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It doesn’t work for me, though… can you post a JSFiddle with the supposedly working code?

Comment: By the way you can post your JSFiddle as an alternative answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the original code was the use of `d.setDate();` instead of `d.setUTCDate();`. Additionally, if the current day was the same day of week as the target day, then the result was incorrect. Simply adding an if statement to check for this case fixes that problem.

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2j49q0ak/1